# automatically trim audio files

Tags: audio, random, extract, code-snippets

I'm trying to extract snippets (3-5 sec.) from a large collection of audio files.

I would like to do this with a shell script. I found basically nothing on the internet, so I'm asking here.

I'm also familiar with perl, php and java - I don't care what language will do, I just want to job done :)

Scenario: I got a large archive of audio files in very high resolution. I need to extract a very short snippet in low resolution for a preview (3 to 5 sec. is extremely short but that's what we need). Being a huge fan of shell scripting, I was hoping to automatize a process that extracts the snippet at RANDOM onset time... is it really too much to ask? :)

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash to automatically set lengths on the audio according to this blog:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I checked lots of sites and forums, and I discovered that there are a number of command line sound processors out there. But I'm afraid I lack the skills to install and run what they require, including your suggestion :( Eventually it turned out that [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) supports scripting, I may try that (easier?) way and update this post!